# Given some continuous function $g:\mathbb R_{+}\to \mathbb R_{-}$, and $\lambda >0$, does there exist $C^{1}$ function $\psi$ satisfying the following

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Given some continuous function $g:\mathbb R_{+}\to \mathbb R_{-}$, and $\lambda >0$, does there exist a $C^{1}$ $\psi$ such that

$$ g(t) =\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi(t)+\lambda\psi(t), \; \psi(0)=0?$$

I am rusty on ODEs but in my view, since $g$ is continuous and (trivially) locally Lipschitz continuous in the second argument (there is no second argument), and hence a unique maximal solution must exist?

I am very unsure on this. Any ideas?

Comment: Does $\Bbb R_+$ contain $0$?

Comment: @s.harp No, it does not contain zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ODE you are interested in is a inhomogenous linear differential equation of first order and there is no magic to it at all. Let $g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ continuous (else your initial condition makes no sense). Then the solution is given by
$$\psi(x) = \biggl(\int_0^x g(t) \mathrm e^{\lambda t} \, \mathrm dt + c \biggr) \mathrm e^{-\lambda x} \qquad (x \in \mathbb R)$$
for a suitable constant $c \in \mathbb R$. Using your inital condition we observe
$c = \psi(0) = 0$. Thus, the solution is given by
$$\psi(x) = \int_0^x g(t) \mathrm e^{\lambda (t - x)} \, \mathrm dt \qquad (x \in \mathbb R).$$
Obviously, the solution is maximal but you can restrict it to $\mathbb R_+$ if that fits your application better.